# Removing list items in C# / XNA

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, synchronization, particles

I am a beginner with XNA Game Studios and want to learn some basics in game programming.
I am currently creating a small space shooter, something like a variation of Space Invaders.

To make my rockets look better I've created some smoke trails to follow them, but would like to remove them after some time (400 milliseconds) so the screen is not blocked by that smoke.
To achieve this I have created the following code, which seems pretty logical to me.

```cs
for(int i=0; i < rocketPosition.Count; i++)
{
    rocketPosition[i] = new Vector2(rocketPosition[i].X, rocketPosition[i].Y - rocketSpeed);
    Vector2 smokePosition = rocketPosition[i];
    smokePosition.X += Rocket.Width / 2 + smokeTexture.Width / 2 + randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
    smokePosition.Y += Rocket.Height + randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
    smokeList.Add(new Particle(smokePosition, gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds));
    if (rocketPosition[i].Y < 0 - Rocket.Height)
    {
        rocketPosition.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < smokeList.Count; i++)
{
    if (smokeList[i].Time < gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds - smokeDuration)
    {
        smokeList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Particle is a class I created in order to have both the creation-time of the list item (which represents the smoke particle), as well as its position Vector2.

However instead of deleting the smoke trail from bottom to top it stops in between and looks like the following picture:
[image: Smoke trail with holes in between]

I hope someone can help me with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing an item from the iterating list decrement the count therefore:

```
for(int i=rocketPosition.Count; i > 0 ; i--)
{
   rocketPosition[i] = new Vector2(rocketPosition[i].X, rocketPosition[i].Y - rocketSpeed);
   Vector2 smokePosition = rocketPosition[i];
   smokePosition.X += Rocket.Width / 2 + smokeTexture.Width / 2 + randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
   smokePosition.Y += Rocket.Height + randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
   smokeList.Add(new Particle(smokePosition, gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds));
   if (rocketPosition[i].Y < 0 - Rocket.Height)
   {
       rocketPosition.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}

for(int i = smokeList.Count; i  > 0 ; i--)
{
   if (smokeList[i].Time < gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds - smokeDuration)
   {
       smokeList.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It is still the same problem.

Comment: Are you calling the repaint after removing the smoke?

Comment: I do call the Draw method. The smoke is drawn in a foreach loop, which means that deleted indices of the array aren't painted. So I suppose they aren't even correctly removed from the array.

Comment: you need to add break point on the 'if' condition and step through to see if the items have been removed from the list.

Comment: Some particles get deleted from the list, some do not. I have no clue why, in my understanding of my own code it should work. Would be great if someone could post how he would have made that possible.

Comment: What type are these rocketPosition[i].Y and Rocket.Height, if they are not the same type then there is resolution bug in this line of code "if (rocketPosition[i].Y < 0 - Rocket.Height)", you need to add a trace on this line every time when hit.

Comment: you do that by set a break point, right click on the break point, this will show context menu. On the context menu select the item "When Hit". On the "When Breakpoint is hit" dialog box select check box Print a Message, inside the text box paste this text "Rocket Position = {rocketPosition[i].Y}, Height = {Rocket.Height}" do not include the double quotes. also tick the "Continue Execution" check box so the code run through.

Comment: On the output window will show your trace, from the trace you can figure out, that when the 'if' condition fails and doesn't remove the item from the list.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jegan. The "Rocket.Height" wasn't the problem (Texture2 Rocket is the texture of the rocket), but when I created the Breakpoint on the time-section I found out the values of smokeList[i].Time were pretty weird. So I tried to use "gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds" instead of ".Milliseconds" and now it works perfectly.